# Touchpad starts requiring 2 fingers - way to fix?

Tags: touchpad

Is there a way to restore single finger function on touchpad without having to reboot?

After using touchpad for a while it often starts requiring 2 fingers on the touchpad to move the cursor and actions that would require 2 fingers then start requiring 3. Single finger is ignored entirely.

My touchpad driver appears to be: ELAN0674:00 04F3:3193 Touchpad

but executing the following does NOT correct the issue:

`xinput disable "ELAN0674:00 04F3:3193 Touchpad" && xinput enable "ELAN0674:00 04F3:3193 Touchpad"`

Rebooting always corrects the issue.

Comment: Does this happen after resuming from suspend? Or is it something that occurs after a certain amount of active use? 

Comment: When it happened today it was from active use but it did happen not long after a resume. Computer was locked and asleep. I resumed and did some work with single finger for several minutes  and then single finger stopped working as I was using.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the Terminal output of `journalctl | grep i2c-hid` and the version of Ubuntu you're using? This is something I've seen in the past, but it was resolved a couple of years ago 

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04. There is no output from ```journalctl | grep i2c-hid``` I tried running it with and without sudo. just blank. Should I edit question to report that it is blank output?

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 is about the be out of support so there's no point in troubleshooting.

Comment: I am experiencing this issue on Arch Linux, and it seems to be related to the lid closing. https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/issues/536 Sometimes, the issue is fixed by closing and opening the lid. Sometimes, it doesn't fix it. I have no clue why this is happening.

Comment: I am experiencing this issue on debian with kernel 5.17.11 on a Thinkpad X1 Gen 9. It occurs intermittently. I had a hypothesis that this had something to do with palm detection, and tried turning it off and then back on. That worked once. I'm now having the same issue and that trick isn't working. Super annoying.

Comment: Same here. Dell XPS13. Ubuntu+Gnome+Wayland.

Comment: Same issue. Has this been reported to Ubuntu? If so, could someone link to the bug report?

Answer (score 5):

I did solved this using Gnome Tweaks to configure laptop lid action.

In **General** tab, I checked "Suspend when laptop lid is closed", then closed the lid and the issue no longer appears (after several tries).

In **Keyboard & Mouse** tab, not sure if it does something but I disabled Mouse Click Emulation.

Install this tool via `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`

Comment: this weirdly solved it for me. unchecked and re-checked and 1 finger is back.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem today.   I was able to work around it by switching to one of the virtual terminals and then back to the desktop.

In my case this was CTRL+ALT+F3, then you can use ALT+LEFT_ARROW until you get your desktop back.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue with Ubuntu 22.04 and a Dell Precision 5560.
For me it seemed to happen after coming out of sleep.
`journalctl | grep i2c-hid` also did not output anything for me.

It happens occasionally.
I have this laptop a couple of months already and have seen it about 6 times or so.
Another interesting fact is that now that I'm typing this, the issue suddenly disappeared.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1242275)